# How do I change text multiple times in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm just getting into jquery and I'm freaking loving it.

At the moment, I'm trying to create the following, seemingly-simple scenario: text is displayed on-screen, and every time the main-content is clicked, the text fades in and out to a different set of text.

Now I've been able to pull this off when it's transitioning from one text to another, but I haven't been able to chain anything else in there for some reason. Any tips would be really appreciated!

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="mainContent">
    <h3 id="bodyText">This is the original text</h>
</div>
```

And here's the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mainContent').click(function () {
        $('#bodyText').fadeOut(function () {
            $(this).text("This is the new text!").fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

*Edit:

Maybe "chain" isn't the proper term - I'm simply trying to allow the user to change the text on-screen a certain number of times (almost like navigating between slides in a basic slideshow in powerpoint) by clicking in the main content area. Thanks for all your answers and suggestions so far, I'm figuring out how to implement your solutions.

Comment: what do you mean 'chain anything else in there'?

Comment: You want to remove the fade effect when new text updated ?

Comment: Please red and update your question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to read about event bubbling in this case, Click events won't bubble down the DOM tree. You have to use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live) instead. But in the latest version of jQuery [`.live()` has been deprecated](http://liveisdeprectaed.com/) so you have to use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) event. As far as repeating this is concerned you have to loop via this and that can be acheived via [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each)

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much. I really do need to dive deeper into the documentation!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add fade-out effect on-click and the use $.ajax to get different text from a PHP page and display that as fade-in effect.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

```
$('#mainContent').unbind('click'); Or you can have livequery() instead.
```

............................

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mainContent').click(function () {
        $('#bodyText').fadeOut(function () {
            $(this).text("This is the new text!").fadeIn();
            $('#mainContent').unbind('click');
            // Or what ever binding you want to add.
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Sahal - is binding a way to link event handlers together or am I missing the mark? I'll try this out in my code and get back to you!

Comment: Yaah, biding is nothing but you are adding an event handler to html tags